# Reading one bit from a pbm (portable bitmap image)

Tags: c#, bitmap

I want to read a pbm (portable bitmap format) image having depth one bit per pixel and store that data in a file, so I can perform some operation on bits.

I think in C# the smallest data that can be read is 1 byte so how can I read a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't read a bit directly. But you can read a byte and then get the bits from that byte. Or, better yet, read a bunch of bytes into an array and then create a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx).

Or ... is this "portable bitmap format" supported directly by the [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class? `Bitmap` does support a 1 bit per pixel format. It might be as simple as calling the `Bitmap` constructor to load from a file or a stream.

More information on your problem will get you a better answer.